# Android: Making Bitmaps Disappear When Touched

Tags: android, bitmap, touch-event

As is, 100 pink circles (same bitmap) appear scattered randomly over the phone screen (as is supposed to).  When I tap one of the circles, that circle should disappear (change to the background color).  I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of Android and View in general.I think I have a couple obvious errors (that are not so obvious to me, but I've been staring at it so long that I figured I needed some help).  Currently, the screen shows the random circles but nothing more.  Touching the screen does nothing.  Any better ideas to make the circles disappear? It recently reorganized all the bitmaps when you touched it, but I did something recently, and it stopped.  The bitmap is 30px by 30px.

```
public class DrawV extends View {
    private Bitmap bit_dot;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public int[] width_array = new int[100];
    public int[] height_array = new int[100];
    private View dotV = (View)findViewById(R.id.bigdocpic);//bitmap
    Random rand = new Random();

public DrawV(Context context) {
    super(context);
    bit_dot = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dot_catch);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;  
}

@Override
//draws 100 randomly placed similar bitmaps
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int height_dimension;
    int width_dimension;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        height_dimension = rand.nextInt(height) + 1;
        width_dimension = rand.nextInt(width) + 1;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bit_dot, width_dimension, height_dimension, null);
        width_array[i] = width_dimension;//
        height_array[i] = height_dimension;//
    } 
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Path path = new Path();
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if ((event.getX() == width_array[i]) && (event.getY() == height_array[i]))
            c.drawCircle(width_array[i], height_array[i], 15, p);
    }
    invalidate();
    return false;//false or true?
}

//set visibility of bitmap to invisible
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    dotV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    invalidate();
    return false;//false or true? not understanding
}}
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Your onTouchEvent isn't really doing anything important as-is, and you don't have the concept of a circle object.

onDraw should really be drawing these circles from an array/list created earlier - say a List<MyCircles> or MyCircles[]. On touch, you could iterate through all of your circles until you find one that is closest, remove that circle from the array or list, then invalidate.

The reason nothing is happening at all is even though you're drawing those circles again in onTouchEvent, you're redrawing everything yet again in onDraw (invalidate() calls draw/onDraw).

Ideally, create your list of circles in your initializer, draw them in onDraw, and update them in onTouch (That is, delete). There may be a simpler way to do this but this is, at the very least, a more proper approach.

Comment: @Thyhme Cypher:  Thanks for the info.  However, how would from clicking could you delete the relevant circle?

Comment: As you already are, you'd determine which circle it is, then call your_List.remove(index_of_matching_circle) to remove it from your List. Then, when you call invalidate (Or more efficiently, call invalidate giving the square area around the circle so only that area redraws) onDraw will get called and redraw only the circles that remain. Since the circle is now gone, it won't get drawn.

From what I understand about Android, the area that is marked for redraw is automatically cleared to the canvas color (Which I believe is transparent, but the view's draw() defaultly draws the background color.